# Do Callable Cloud Functions Ensure a Valid Token when Called

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am calling a callable cloud function from a Javascript frontend and when calling Firebase in the past I would chain `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(...` before my call to the backend to ensure I had a valid token. Now that I am switching to callable cloud functions, I am wondering if this token refresh check is embedded in the callable itself or if I have to still check that my token is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a method returned by the callable builder, like `const myFunc = httpsCallable(funcName); myFunc(/* data */);`, only the current ID token is attached. If the token has not yet expired, it is not forcibly refreshed.

At least for the JavaScript SDK, this is seen in the source code of [`packages/functions/src/service.ts`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/47b34555c7ab8180f901007320368a83cf83a786/packages/functions/src/service.ts#L248-L283) and [`packages/functions/src/context.ts`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/47b34555c7ab8180f901007320368a83cf83a786/packages/functions/src/context.ts#L88-L100):

```js
// in packages/functions/src/service.ts
const context = await functionsInstance.contextProvider.getContext();
if (context.authToken) {
  headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.authToken;
}


// in packages/functions/src/context.ts
async getAuthToken(): Promise<string | undefined> {
  if (!this.auth) {
    return undefined;
  }

  try {
    const token = await this.auth.getToken();
    return token?.accessToken;
  } catch (e) {
    // If there's any error when trying to get the auth token, leave it off.
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

This essentially leads to the following decisions:

- If Firebase Authentication isn't loaded, return `undefined` (don't attach any tokens).
- If the no one is logged in, return `null` (don't attach any tokens).
- If the token has expired, attempt to get a fresh one (and then attach it to the request).
- If the token can't be obtained, return `undefined` (don't attach any tokens).
- If the token has not expired, return the access token (and then attach it to the request).

Even though token expiry is handled by the SDK, you can still forcibly freshen up the token by using `getIdToken(/* forciblyRefresh: */ true)` before calling the function. The Cloud Functions SDK will call the Admin SDK to verify whatever token is sent as soon as the request is received regardless.

Aside from that, you can further enhance the security of your Cloud Function by enforcing a cutoff on how long ago the user signed into their account for privileged actions like account deletion, changing service account details and so on. This is done using the `auth_time` claim inside the access token's data or the [`authTime` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.IDTokenResult#authtime) on the id token object.

Comment: But so it will attempt to refresh the token if it has expired - great! Is the reason you recommend (also do you have a source - docs etc) force-refreshing before a privileged action because someone could be using a token that they should not have access to and force-refreshing would will stop that? Is that a practical vector of attack? Are security concerns the only reason to force refresh the token?

Comment: @AlexWilliams I misspoke regarding the token, I meant to suggest reauthenticating rather than just a token refresh (as the token is validated on the server side anyway). This practice of reauthenticating before doing something sensitive is [enforced by Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) for the client SDKs. I just use the same approach for certain sensitive features such as using a cloud function to blast out push notifications with a custom message to all users. Helps protect against bad actors that physically gain access to your PC.